# Show that A has a limit point but every subsequence doesn't converge to that point

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[-1,1] \cup \{9\}$ Define $$\mathscr T=\mathscr T_{std} \cup \{G \cup \{9\}:G \in \mathscr T_{std} \text{ and }0\in G \}$$
where $\mathscr T_{std}$ is the standard topology of $[-1,1]$ induced by $\Bbb R$

Define a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ by $x_0=9$ and $x_n=1/n$ and let $A=\{x_n:n=1,2,...\}$

Show that A has a limit point but every subsequence doesn't converge to that point

I guess the answer is $9$. But every open set containing $9$ also containing an open interval $(a,b) \text { where } a\lt 0 \lt b$, which means I can find some $N$ s.t. $x_n \in (a,b)$ for $n\gt N$

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: *scratches head* The sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, hence all of its subsequences are convergent too, with the same limits, $0$ and $9$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Errrr,do you mean that the question is wrong at the first place? Also do you mean that the sequence has two limits?

Comment: Unless a non-standard terminology was introduced before the exercise was given, yes, it's wrong. And indeed, the sequence has two limits.

Comment: The order of words matters.  In "every sub-sequence does not converge", to what does the "not" apply ? To "converge".... So "every sub-sequence does not converge" asserts that every sub-sequence has the property of "failing to converge". On the other hand, in "not every sub-sequence converges" it is the "every" that is negated.